# Recursive and iteration fibonacci

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to make it where it prints the recursive part of the code out the same as it prints out the iteration.
Fibonacci sequence in iteration

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

The ending of the fibonacci sequence at 9 is 34
Time : 1 .     like so , but every time I try a loop to print I get some weird answers, Not really sure what to add to the method.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class fibonacciRecursive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Dustin Willingham 
         * Class: CSCI 1302 Mon-Wed Cartersville 
         *Lets user enter the last number of a fibonacci sequence
         *then it takes the number and runs the fibonacci sequence in recursive and iteration method
         *It outputs the answer for both and the time
         */

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number you want the Fibonacci sequence to go to:");
        int fibNumb = in.nextInt();

        //Print and timing for the Fibonacci sequence with the Recursive method
        System.out.println("Fibonacci sequence in recursion");
        //start of the timer
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("The ending of the fibonacci sequence at " + fibNumb + " is " + fibonacciRec(fibNumb));
        System.out.print("Time : ");
        //print out the timer
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);





        //Print and timing for the Fibonacci sequence with the Iteration method
        System.out.println("\n" + "Fibonacci sequence in iteration");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("The ending of the fibonacci sequence at " + fibNumb + " is " + fiboacciIte(fibNumb));
        System.out.print("Time : ");
        System.out.print(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);


        in.close();
    }

    // Recursive method for the Fibonacci sequence
    public static int fibonacciRec(int fibNumb) {


        if ((fibNumb == 1) || (fibNumb == 0)) {
            return fibNumb;



         }
        int answer = fibonacciRec(fibNumb - 1) + fibonacciRec(fibNumb - 2);
        return answer;
    }

    //Iteration method for the Fibonacci sequence
    static int fiboacciIte(int fibNumb) {
        int a = 0, b = 1, c = 1;
        for (int d = 0; d < fibNumb; d++) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            System.out.println(a);
            c = a + b;
        }
        return a;   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a separate argument to the recursive function, which gives the highest Fibonacci subscript (`fibNumb`) reached so far. If the current subscript is greater than this counter, update it and print the current Fibonacci number.

The counter must be passed by reference as the value will need to be updated *before* recursion unfolds. We can create a custom class for it:

```
private static class Counter
{
    private int value;
    public Counter() { value = 0; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
    public void increment() { value++; }
}
```

Pass the same instance to each recursive call and increment along the way:

```
private static int fibonacciRec_internal(int fibNumb_cur, Counter fibNumb_max) {
    int answer = (fibNumb_cur <= 1) ? fibNumb_cur :
                 fibonacciRec_internal(fibNumb_cur - 1, fibNumb_max) +
                 fibonacciRec_internal(fibNumb_cur - 2, fibNumb_max);
    if (fibNumb_max.getValue() < fibNumb_cur) {
        fibNumb_max.increment();
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

And finally write a wrapper function to hide this counter class and its usage details:

```
public static int fibonacciRec(int fibNumb)
{
    Counter max = new Counter();
    return fibonacciRec_internal(fibNumb, max);
}
```

Results are as expected:

```
// fibonacciRec(10);
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```

---

Even better, we could create a wrapper class for *all* of the above, and use the same object for every `fibonacciRec` call instead of creating a new one. It's a pretty trivial modification so I'll leave it to you to figure out the what and the how.